# Keras LSTM appears to be fitting the end of time-series input instead of the prediction target

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, prediction

To preface this, I have plenty of experience with python and moderate experience building and using machine learning networks. That being said, this is the first LSTM I have made aside from some of the cookie-cutter examples available, so any help is appreciated. I feel like this is a problem with a simple solution and that I have just been looking at this code for far too long to see it.

This model is made in a python3.5 venv using Keras with a tensorflow backend.

In short, I am trying to make predictions of some temporal data using the data itself as well as a few mathematical permutations of this data, creating four input features. I am building a time-series input from the prior 60 data points and specifying the prediction target to be 60 data points in the future.

Shape of complete training data (input)(target): (2476224, 60, 4)    (2476224)

Shape of single data "point" (input)(target):       (1, 60, 4)          (1)

What appears to be happening is that the trained model has fit the trailing value of my input time-series (the current value) instead of the target I have provided it (60 cycles in the future).

What is interesting is that the loss function seems to be calculating according to the correct prediction target, yet the model is not converging to the proper solution.

I have no idea why the model should be doing this. My first thought was that I was preprocessing my data incorrectly and feeding it the wrong target. I have tested my input formatting of the data extensively and am pretty confident that I am providing the model with he correct target and input information.

In one instance, I had increased the learning rate a tad such that the model converged to a local minima. This testing loss of this convergence was very similar to the loss of my preferred learning rate (still quite high). But the predictions were still of the "current value". Why is this so?

Here is how I created my model:

```py
def create_model():
   lstm_model = Sequential()
   lstm_model.add(CuDNNLSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, time_step, train_input.shape[2]),
                       stateful=True, return_sequences=True,
                       kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
   lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
   lstm_model.add(CuDNNLSTM(60))
   lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
   lstm_model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
   lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
   optimizer = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=params["lr"])
   lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
   return lstm_model
```

This is how I am pre-processing the data. The first function, build_timeseries, constructs my input-output pairs. I believe this is working correctly (but please correct me if I am wrong). The second function trims the pairs to fit the batch size. I do the exact same for the test input/target.

```py
train_input, train_target = build_timeseries(train_input, time_step, pred_horiz, 0)
train_input = trim_dataset(train_input, batch_size)
train_target = trim_dataset(train_target, batch_size)
```

```py
def build_timeseries(mat, TIME_STEPS, PRED_HORIZON, y_col_index):
    # y_col_index is the index of column that would act as output column
    dim_0 = mat.shape[0]  # num datasets
    dim_1 = mat.shape[1]  # num features
    dim_2 = mat.shape[2]  # num datapoints

    # Reformatted matrix
    mat = mat.swapaxes(1, 2)

    x = np.zeros((dim_0*(dim_2-PRED_HORIZON), TIME_STEPS, dim_1))
    y = np.zeros((dim_0*(dim_2-PRED_HORIZON),))

    k = 0
    for i in range(dim_0):  # Iterate through datasets
        for j in range(TIME_STEPS, dim_2-PRED_HORIZON):
            x[k] = mat[i, j-TIME_STEPS:j]
            y[k] = mat[i, j+PRED_HORIZON, y_col_index]
            k += 1
    print("length of time-series i/o", x.shape, y.shape)
    return x, y

def trim_dataset(mat, batch_size):
    no_of_rows_drop = mat.shape[0] % batch_size
    if(no_of_rows_drop > 0):
        return mat[no_of_rows_drop:]
    else:
        return mat
```

Lastly, this is how I call the actual model.

```py
history = model.fit(train_input, train_target, epochs=params["epochs"], verbose=2, batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=True, validation_data=(test_input, test_target), callbacks=[es, mcp])
```

As the model converges, I expect it to predict values close to the specified targets I had fed it. However instead, its predictions align much more closely with the trailing value of the time-series data (or the current value). Though, on the other hand, the model appears to be evaluating the loss according to the specified target.... Why is it working this way and how can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don´t you have to set return_sequences=true in the other layers too?